# How to suppress mouse over error messages on graphics

Tags: graphics

How do I suppress these they are preventing me from getting coordinates.

[image]

Here is the code to create the graphic if it helps.

```
CreateDocument[
 Style[Show[
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.0003], Circle[{0, 0}, LcircRad]}, 
    ImageSize -> 1000],
     ParallelTable[
      Graphics[{Thickness[0.0003], 
      Circle[{xcircle[[i]], ycircle[[i]]}, ScircRad]}], {i, 1, nlens, 
     1}],
  ParallelTable[
    Graphics[{Thickness[0.00025], Red, 
      Line[{{xint[k, o], yint[k, o]}, {xint[k, o + 1], 
     yint[k, o + 1]}}]}], {k, nrays}, {o, 
     Dimensions[xintmatrix][[2]] - 1}],
   PlotRange -> {{-LcircD, LcircD}, {0, LcircD}}], 
  AutoStyleOptions -> {"HighlightFormattingErrors" -> False}]
 ]
```

Comment: Your code does not run -- missing definitions for several variables.  I cannot check my solution idea.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you can suppress the tooltip-on-formatting-error by setting `"FormattingErrorTooltips"` (or other related options) to `False` in the given notebook, or in the front-end:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], AutoStyleOptions -> {
     "FormattingErrorStyle" -> {FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0.33, 0.33], 
            Background -> RGBColor[1., 0.33, 0.33, 0.15]}, (* pink style *)
     "FormattingErrorTooltips" -> False, (* suppress tooltips *)
     "HighlightFormattingErrors" -> True (* suppress error indication *)
     }]
```